# Story about a boy who could wish to be someone else and would gain their skills

Tags: story-identification, books

Young adult novel, that I read roughly 20 years ago. The main character was a teenage boy who discovers that he can wish to be someone and he would gain their skills, though he still keeps his own body (however, that doesn't seem to be a limitation).

He's playing a baseball game, and says, "I wish I was Babe Ruth(1)" and is suddenly able to play really well. His power lasted a limited time, maybe 90 minutes, and once he wishes to be someone, he can't wish to be them again.

I think his name might have been Asher or Ashton. There was also a scene in a zoo, and there might have been a picture of him at the zoo on the cover, but I'm not sure. It seemed like it was a part of a larger series, but I only ever read this book.

1 It might not have been Babe Ruth, the name meant nothing to me at the time, but I'm pretty sure it was a baseball player of some kind.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks for the heads up. I was asleep when you responded. :)

Comment: ^_^ Cool. You just didn't have an accepted answer on your profile, so I figured I'd cover all of the bases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're looking for *[The Amazing Power of Ashur Fine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/218556.The_Amazing_Power_of_Ashur_Fine)* by Donald J. Sobol (best known for his *Encyclopedia Brown* series).

[image: Front cover of The Amazing Power of Ashur Fine]

> Ashur Fine is no typical high school kid. Ashur possesses the Power. He can become any person, living or dead, by simply wishing to be. With the Power on his side, Ashur sets out to find the culprit who mugged Aunt Ruth. But the tables turn—and soon it's Ashur himself who's being stalked! The adventure leads Ashur smack into the middle of an international plot!

He gets his powers from an elephant at the zoo named Methuselah. Chapter 3 is entitled "Welcome Back, Babe Ruth", and is probably the baseball section you remember (I don't currently have the copy I checked out from the library before). Another bit of excerpt that Google Books popped up for me suggests that fifteen minutes is the power limit, after which they're inaccessible. FWIW, he's being targeted in part because the villain knows that he can summon the spirit of a fellow who hid a large sum of money in a bridge he designed to learn of its location.

I had encountered this before when posting an answer to [Science Fiction - Boy recieves powers from elephant at the zoo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124340/science-fiction-boy-recieves-powers-from-elephant-at-the-zoo) where the person had figured it out and left a comment saying as much. Your mention of the boy's name reminded me of this and I also remembered there was an elephant involved, so I searched on this site for answers involving elephants and found my answer. It is a standalone book, although I agree with you that it might have been a good setup for a series, semi-educational at that as he would have to figure out new people to borrow powers from.

Comment: That looks and sounds like the book! It's a pity it wasn't a series, I remember the ending feeling a bit incomplete, but maybe that was just me wanting to read more about this character. Thanks.

Comment: You're not wrong; the book ends with some major questions unanswered about what happens next.